# Initialize not working when app restarted

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Hi I am saving some data to cloud firestore when user signin with google. I have a function that Initialize all the data of user from Firestore

```
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).getUserUID)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      initUserName = doc.data()!["username"];
      initUserDisplayName = doc.data()!["name"];
      initUserAvatar = doc.data()!["avatar"];
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

and in my homepage i have init state

```
 void initState() {
    Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).initUserData(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

everything is working fine. But when i restart my application it shows that

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'userAvatar' has not been initialized.
```

Comment: Maybe key issue initUserAvatar = doc.data()!["avatar"]; // here avatar or userAvatar?

Comment: No its working when i login and but when i restart app it stops working

Comment: Error means that variable userAvatar marked as late was accessed when in null state. You should check out https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/LateInitializationError-class.html and https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables

Comment: Maybe you should keep your initialisation code in onStart() method , instead of onCreate() method.